# Telegram bot response too late

Tags: node.js, heroku, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I created simple telegram bot to filter bad words, it works perfectly when I run on local, but response too late after I deployed to Heroku service.

Full Code

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api')
const bot = new TelegramBot('myKeyIsHere', { polling: true })
var Filter = require('bad-words')

var filter = new Filter()

bot.on('message', async (msg) => {
  const checkMsg = filter.clean(msg.text)
  if (msg.text !== checkMsg) {
    let chat_id = msg.chat.id
    let message_id = msg.message_id
    bot.deleteMessage(chat_id, message_id)
    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, `${msg.from.first_name} says: ${checkMsg}`)
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Heroku is not a good host for the Telegram bot, because after a long period of inactivity Heroku falls asleep

Comment: This isn't what the OP asked